# Trouble with onsen switch triggering callback

Tags: android, switch-statement, onsen-ui

I am trying to implement a switch element using onsen ui to enable/disable BT and having trouble talking to the controller js.

```
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('app', ['onsen']);
        app.controller('Controller', function($scope) {
            $scope.item=[{selected:true}];
            $scope.enBT = function(){
                var Checked = BTSwitch.isChecked();
                alert(Checked);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Below is my HTML code.

```
    <div class="app">
        <h1 >Apache Cordova using Onsen</h1><br /><br />
        <ons-span id="enBluetooth" style="font-size: 40">  Enable bluetooth 
            <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox" var="BTSwitch" ng-model="item.selected" ng-change="enBT" class="switch__input">
                <div class="switch__toggle"></div>
            </label>
        </ons-span><br />
    </div>
```

The switch UI displays but I cannot get it to respond to ng-change nor does it show the startup state as true, which is set in JS. Please can someone tell me what I am doing incorrectly? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to set `ng-app` attribute in the wrapper element, or call `angular.bootstrap(document, ['app'])`, to run the app.
Second, you need to set `ng-controller` attribute in the wrapper element to bind the controller to the view.
Third, `$scope.item` doesn't need to be an array. Just `$scope.item = {selected: true}` is enough.

And there are a few other mistakes in your code. Try below snippet.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['onsen']);
app.controller('Controller', function($scope) {
  $scope.item= {selected:true};
  $scope.enBT = function(){
    var Checked = $scope.item.selected;
    alert(Checked);
  };
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.6/build/css/onsen-css-components.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.6/build/css/onsenui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.6/build/js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.6/build/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app" class="app" ng-controller="Controller">
  <h1 >Apache Cordova using Onsen</h1><br /><br />
  <ons-span id="enBluetooth" style="font-size: 40">  Enable bluetooth 
    <label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox" var="BTSwitch" ng-model="item.selected" ng-change="enBT()" class="switch__input">
      <div class="switch__toggle"></div>
    </label>
  </ons-span><br />
</div>
```